# getAuthCode Does Nothing in Mini Program Studio

Tags: vodapay-miniprogram

I have my website docked in a web-view in my mini program, and I have got the full message cycle working both ways, with the mini program communicating with my website and the website communicating with the mini program. However, I'm trying to retrieve user details and the first step is to call getAuthCode as per the docs.  But I get nothing - no errors, no response, no failure.

```
alert('started');
my.getAuthCode({
    scopes: ['USER_ID'],
    success: (result) => {
        alert('success');
    },
    failed: (result) => {
        alert('failure');
    },
});
alert('finished');
```

In the code above, I get to the 'started' message, but not the 'finished', and I get no other errors, whichever way I try to catch and display them.  I can call other methods on the `my` object.

I am running in the emulator/simulator in Mini Program Studio - is that the problem? Why do I get no response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I had placed the above JavaScript in the web view, whereas it needed to go in the mini app.  I then use postMessage to send the auth code back to the web view.